# I need to track video image based on color histogram bins . like this example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram#Example_1

Tags: matlab

hey i'm trying to do color histogram based on bins 
like this example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram#Example_1 
for now ,i just did for 3 bins by my self but i want to do for more than 3 .

```
    function H=my_hist(img)
SIZE=size(img);
H=[0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0];
for i=1:3
    H(:,:,i)=[0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0];%%the template
end
for row=1:SIZE(1)%%%%%the main function for calculating bins
    for col=1:SIZE(2)
        %%check the bin of color
            if(img(row,col,1)<(1/3))
                red=1;
            elseif(img(row,col,1)<(2/3))
                red=2;
            elseif(img(row,col,1)<=1)
                red=3;
            end
            if(img(row,col,2)<(1/3))
                green=1;
            elseif(img(row,col,2)<(2/3))
                green=2;
            elseif(img(row,col,2)<=1)
                green=3;
            end
            if(img(row,col,3)<(1/3))
                blue=1;
            elseif(img(row,col,3)<(2/3))
                blue=2;
            elseif(img(row,col,3)<=1)
                blue=3;
            end
            H(red,green,blue)=H(red,green,blue)+1;%%fill histogram of bins
    end
end
end
```

can see matrix 3*3*3 for 3 bins .
I think that the code will be very long if i do it myself.
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

For collecting 3D histogram with `n`x`n`x`n` bins you can use the following stages:

- Discretize RGB values to `n` levels each.
  Example: for `n` = 4, all values will be 0, 1, 2 or 3.
- Convert Discretized RGB to 2D image, each element is equivalent to digit in "base n".
  Think about is a three digits number in decimal base like:
  Getting 375 from the digits 3, 7, 5, when 3 is the MSD (most significant digit) and 5 is the LSD (least significant digit).
- Collect histogram of 2D image using [histcounts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) MATLAB function.
  Collect histogram with with n^3 bins.
- Reshape the collected histogram to `n`x`n`x`n` 3D matrix.

Here is a sample code:

```
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
RGB = double(RGB)/256; %Convert image from uint8 to double (range [0, 0.9961]).

n = 3; %Number of histogram bins.

%Discretize: 1/n lowr elements goes to zero, next 1/n elements goes 1 next 1/n elements goes 2...
%The following formula applies uniform quantization, when range RGB is [0, 0.9999].
dRGB = floor(RGB * n); %In case of n = 3, discretizedRGB elements are going to be 0, 1, 2 (and 3)

%Convert dRGB to 2D image, each element is equivalent to digit in "base n".
%Think about is a three digits number in decimal base like: 
%Getting 375 from the digits 3, 7, 5, when 3 is the MSD (most significant digit) and 5 is the LSD (least significant digit).
%I = dRGB(:,:,1) * n^2 + dRGB(:,:,2) * n + dRGB(:,:,3); %Take red as MSD
I = dRGB(:,:,1) + dRGB(:,:,2) * n + dRGB(:,:,3) * n^2; %Take blue as MSD

%Collect histogram of 2D image, with n^3 bins
H = histcounts(I(:), n^3);

%Reshape histogram to 3D matrix.
H3 = reshape(H, [n, n, n]);

%Check if result is equal to result of my_hist
if n == 3
    refH3 = my_hist(RGB);
    all(H3(:) == refH3(:))
end
```

As you can see, with n = 3, the result equals to your implementation result.

---

Remark: Collecting 3D histogram is not very useful.
In most cases you need to collect separate histogram for each color channel:

```
R = RGB(:, :, 1);
G = RGB(:, :, 2);
B = RGB(:, :, 3);
rH = histcounts(R(:), n); %Red channel histogram
gH = histcounts(G(:), n); %Green channel histogram
bH = histcounts(B(:), n); %Blue channel histogram
```

And in some case histogram of brightness:

```
Gray = rgb2gray(RGB);
grayH = histcounts(Gray(:), n); %Histogram of Grayscale equivalent image.
```